# how to use java custom annotation in openapi spec 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

Just wondering if there is a way I can use my custom annotation in openapi specification.

> **Scenario-**
>
> User Object- I need to have notnull validation between username or
> email. either one of these should be provided in request

[image]

For this I can create a custom annotation in code something like `@ValidateUserNameAndEmail`, but not finding a way to apply this in openapi spec and include it like other annotation in generated code.

Answer (score 2):

I use the latest version (6.2.1) of `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` and following works for me.

```
User:
  type: object
  x-class-extra-annotation: "@org.example.ValidateUsernameAndEmail"
  ...
```

The plugin generates following class:

```
@Schema(name = "User ")
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2022-11-24T14:51:09.277810200+01:00[Europe/Prague]")
@org.example.ValidateUsernameAndEmail
public class User {
    ...
}
```

You can also define a field-level annotation using `x-field-extra-annotation` if needed.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible. You can use validation annotation provided by openapi such as @NotNull